# Norm preserving Unitary operators in Rigged Hilbert space

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, unitarity

If we take the free particle Hamiltonian, the eigenvectors (or eigenfunctions), say in position representation, are like $e^{ikx}$. Now these eigenfunctions are non-normalisable,so they don't belong the normal $L^2(\mathbb R^d)$ but the rigged Hilbert space.

My question hereto is that any unitary operator defined as a map in Hilbert space preserves the norm. But in the case of free particle, although the operator $e^{iHt}$ is unitary (since $H$ is hermitian), there is (atleast) no (direct) condition of norm preserval, as the norm cannot be defined for these eigenfunctions.

Now, how can one connect the unitarity of $e^{iHt}$ and norm preserval in this context ?

PS : I know one can use box-normalised wavefunctions and do away with the calculations and then take $L \rightarrow \infty$ limit. But I am rather interested in the actual question of unitarity and norm in rigged Hilbert spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The so-called rigged spaces are made with a triple $(S,\mathscr{H},S')$; where $\mathscr{H}$ is the usual Hilbert space, $S$ is a dense vector subspace of $\mathscr{H}$, and $S'$ the dual of $S$.

Usually when $\mathscr{H}=L^2(\mathbb{R}^d$, then $S$ is taken to be the rapidly decrasing functions, and $S'$ the tempered distributions. If this is the case, then there is no notion of norm for the "extended" eigenvectors in $S'$, since the latter is not a Banach (or metrizable) space.

So even if $e^{-itH}e^{ikx}=e^{-itk^2/2m}e^{ikx}$, and therefore the evolution indeed acts as a phase, there is no norm to be preserved.

The point is that rigged Hilbert spaces are, as far as I know, simply a mathematical convenience to justify the emergence of "generalized eigenvectors" for some (very special) self-adjoint operators that have purely continuous spectrum. If you want to do (meaningful) quantum mechanics, you have to consider states of the Hilbert space, where the evolution is indeed unitary and everything works.

Comment: So you mean to say, there is no such connection between unitarity and norm preserval in a non metrizable space (like rigged Hilbert space).

Comment: Yes; unitarity is defined in Hilbert spaces, and norm preserving operators in Banach spaces are called isometries. The space of distributions is a space that can be endowed with one of the topologies induced by duality with $\mathscr{S}(\mathbb{R}^d)$. Anyways, it is not a metrizable space, so neither Banach nor Hilbert. Hence the *notions* of unitarity and isometry cannot be defined on $S'$.

Comment: But if the notions of unitarity is not defined in $S'$, how can one do quantum mechanics with it and be reconciled with probability conservation. Shouldn't there be an analogous property that can help with the probability interpretation in QM, if yes, what is it ?

Comment: So that is why box normalisation comes in ??

Comment: Of course if you put everything in a box, there is no problem. However removing the box can be very tricky, if you want to do things in a rigorous (and meaningful) fashion.

Comment: Thanks, it would be great if you just remove the comments and put it in the answer for a more comprehensive answer, I will accept your answer :)

Comment: Yes, I would like to know that part too, the limit of $L\rightarrow \infty$ is a very handwaving thing, how does one do it rigorously ? (or should it be another question separately ?)

Comment: I edited the answer ;-) Concerning the limit $L\to\infty$, it would surely be worth another question. I am not a big expert on that, but it is usually done when considering thermodynamic systems. You place yourself in a box of volume $\Lambda$, and then try to take the thermodynamic limit $\Lambda\to \infty$, $N\to\infty$ (number of particles), $N/\Lambda=\rho<\infty$.  In that context, there are some rigorous results that justify, for suitable quantities, the limit.