# Rigorous way of box normalisation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, hilbert-space

This is follow up from an [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/262654/norm-preserving-unitary-operators-in-rigged-hilbert-space/262664#262664) to my previous question about unitarity in rigged Hilbert space. As it turns out, that there is no idea of unitarity in rigged Hilbert space (hence no meaningful QM can be done), we have to resort to techniques like box normalisation for systems like free particle to do physically meaningful quantum mechanics.

In this context, I wish to know how can one rigorously go to $L\rightarrow\infty$ limit which makes my space again a rigged Hilbert space but still my results of QM are valid. This seems to be like a map between rigged Hilbert space to a normal Hilbert space (or atleast a banach space)

PS : By meaningful QM I mean the ideas of probability and its conservation used to relate to physical experiments.

**EDIT** : Some direction in this, as already @yuggib suggested in my previous answer, is the thermodynamic limit of $N\rightarrow\infty$ and $V(\text{or} L^3)\rightarrow\infty$ but $\rho = N/V$ is finite. So is this technique not applicable for single free particle ?

Comment: The probability of finding a quantum in an infinite space is zero. There is nothing that math can do about that. :-)

Comment: Statement accepted :) But I am not sure, how that helps to give me a direction to think about an answer.

Comment: You can go from one quantum to a density of quanta... oops!... now you are dealing with multiple identical particles and you need a many-body wavefunction, which more or less automatically gets you into quantum field theory. Take your pick... particle in a box or QFT... which is the smaller pain?

Comment: @CuriousOne : Please have a look at the recent EDIT in my question, I have a feeling your comment has some overlap to what I am asking but it doesn't get through my head ;)

Comment: The simple fact is that one can't find one thing in an infinite volume...

Comment: Of course, I agree !!! That is the reason why we're doing our calculations in the finite volume; but my question is about how then we take the infinite limit (neglecting the boundary effects) and how rigorous is this. Which is to say more precisely, upto what degree or what precision is this correct ?

Comment: Zero is zero is zero. :-) When did the NSF pay for your infinite size lab, anyway?